# Cortex-M0+ only writes register with breakpoint

Tags: debugging, atmel, cortex-m, atmelstudio

I have an application which only works when a breakpoint is set prior to writing to a register. The particular uC is an Atmel SAMC21 and the issue seems to be when writing to the GCLK peripheral. I write the GEN bits correctly, then set CHEN to enable the channel. With a breakpoint it is enabled correctly. Without the breakpoint, the bit is not set when observed through the Atmel Studio IO debug window. The CAN peripheral this particular channel is attached to hangs when the bit isn't set (as it isn't clocked), but works fine if I set the breakpoint and then allow the program to continue. Their is no other location in code this bit is set or checked, and there is no multithreading.

The offending code:

```
// PCHCTRL[26] GCLK_CAN0
GCLK->PCHCTRL[26].bit.GEN = 7;          // Generic clock generator 7
GCLK->PCHCTRL[26].bit.CHEN = 1;         // The peripheral channel is enabled.
GCLK->PCHCTRL[26].bit.WRTLOCK = 0;      // The peripheral channel and the associated generator registers are not locked.
```

PCHCTRL:

```
union PCHCTRL {
    uint32_t reg;
    struct bit {
        uint32_t GEN:4;
        uint32_t :2;
        uint32_t CHEN:1;
        uint32_t WRTLOCK:1;
        uint32_t :24;
    } bit;
} PCHCTRL[41];
```

I've tried inserting delays between the two writes with no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated as to the cause of this issue!

Answer (score 0):

A quick scan of the datasheet reveals this (emphasis mine):

> 17.5.8. Register Access Protection
>
> All registers with write-access can be optionally write-protected by the Peripheral Access Controller
>   (PAC).
>
> Note: 
>    Optional write-protection is indicated by the "PAC Write-Protection" property in the register
>   description.
>
> **When the CPU is halted in debug mode, all write-protection is automatically disabled. Write-protection
>   does not apply for accesses through an external debugger.**

From that, it sounds an awful lot like your startup code or some other part of the application could be setting the PAC to write-protect GCLK, in which case that's going to need some poking to un-protect it around the modification.

Otherwise, there's also this:

> 17.6.3.1. Enabling a Peripheral Clock
>
> Before a Peripheral Clock is enabled, one of the Generators must be enabled (GENCTRLn.GENEN) and
>   selected as source for the Peripheral Channel by setting the Generator Selection bits in the Peripheral
>   Channel Control register (PCHCTRL.GEN). Any available Generator can be selected as clock source for
>   each Peripheral Channel.
>
> When a Generator has been selected, the peripheral clock is enabled by setting the Channel Enable bit in
>   the Peripheral Channel Control register, PCHCTRLm.CHEN = 1. The PCHCTRLm.CHEN bit must be
>   synchronized to the generic clock domain. PCHCTRLm.CHEN will continue to read as its previous state
>   until the synchronization is complete.

Which suggests you might see something similar if the generator itself isn't correctly set up and enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly due to not waiting for the clock sync before proceeding (hitting a breakpoint causes a delay long enough for it to happen, the CAN and some other devices don't by default freeze on a breakpoint). It needs something along the lines of this to wait for the clock to sync:

```
// Set GCLK_CAN0 to use GCLK generator 8
PCHCTRL26 |= PCHCTRL_CHEN | PCHCTRL_GEN_8; // Bit 6 is CHEN, GEN[3:0] set to 8 = GCLK generator 8
while ((PCHCTRL26 & PCHCTRL_CHEN) == 0) {  // Wait for sync
    // Spin
}
```